# Console ScreenSaver without X11

Tags: debian, console, images, screensaver

I'm trying to setup a very slimmed down console only Debian system to act as a simple slideshow photo display. I know that it is possible to show graphics (I guess using the framebuffer) in the console without running X11 but I haven't been able to track down anything that I could use to display images.

Has anyone actually ever made a console based picture screensaver? Or is there at least some package out there that would get me part of the way there?
I know that there are options for Gnome, KDE, etc... but it would be great if I could keep this build as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't know of any console screensaver, but to begin with you can display images in your console using the `aview` utility.

Comment: That's the ASCII image viewer right? To clarify, I would like it to actually show the full image, not a conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that I found the answer. Debian has a package called [fbi](http://packages.debian.org/stable/fbi) that draws an image to the framebuffer from the console (the real one, not the terminal emulator in X11). Even can do slideshows :)

Comment: Fine. For programming, I remember that I used svgalib, which came with some demos.